# Multiple items in constructor errors

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constructor

Good Day,

I have a C++ Class that looks like this:

```
class WiFlyRNXV{
public:
WiFlyRNXV(byte pinReceive, byte pinSend);                   //Constructor with Pins for UART
SoftwareSerial uart;                                        //SoftwareSerial driver
IRSystem irSystem;
}
```

and the constructor looks like this initially..

```
WiFlyRNXV::WiFlyRNXV(byte pinReceive, byte pinSend) : uart (pinReceive, pinSend){}
```

I had no issues..but once I did this:

```
WiFlyRNXV::WiFlyRNXV(byte pinReceive, byte pinSend) : uart (pinReceive, pinSend),irSystem(8){}
```

It suddenly threw a whole load of errors, including missing brackets, parsing errors etc. in my Main.cpp file. I can't understand why this would happen. Main includes the above class btw.

Comment: as long as i include one item in the constructor it works..two items and i get errors

Comment: Hard to help without the actual errors.

Comment: you need to post error message and IRSystem constructors code

Comment: Does `IRSystem` have a constructor that takes an int?

Comment: ah nvmind it was a clashing #define constant..

Comment: IRSystem had a define that clashes with WiFlyRNXV..and somehow the compiler didn't detect that and threw me a whole load of missing '}' errors instead..crazy

Comment: Maybe you defined it in code that you didn't give us, but there is no type byte in C++.
And you're missing a semicolon at the end of your class definition.

Answer (score 1):

After a class declaration you forgotten to put semicolon.

Try this:

```
class WiFlyRNXV{
public:
WiFlyRNXV(byte pinReceive, byte pinSend);                   //Constructor with Pins for UART
SoftwareSerial uart;                                        //SoftwareSerial driver
IRSystem irSystem;
};
```